# How to get FedEx access token

Tags: ios, swift, fedex

I have created development account on FedEx and get all key and secret.

Now I am trying to call oauth api but didn’t get a access token but getting error as 400.

Developer link https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html

**My code is -**

```
let headers = [
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
    let parameters = [
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "client_id":"client_id",
        "client_secret":"client_secret"
        
    ] as [String : String]

    let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token")! as URL,
                                            cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData! as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
      if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
      } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        print(httpResponse)
      }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

**Error Log -**

(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6000009b0080> { URL: https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
"no-store"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
184
);
"Content-Type" =     (
"application/json"
);
Date =     (
"Mon, 14 Feb 2022 10:33:53 GMT"
);
Pragma =     (
"no-cache"
);
Server =     (
"Layer7-API-Gateway"
);
"Set-Cookie" =     (
"bm_sv=0301466DB0BFD9216A1FA61DA0EC0272~1G4H2uDnGg2TFUuh7DlMXX1JIzwt6bG0fBtlySSfQAkgYesGo8P+MKPPvGVJVn8XzadxNXeGTDpjpOqQBbG1VXH6k5geeiiBP6h+AsUvs+g8hX1utfFuyRCmuHRXGO4lZKsf6jxJU2G1plXqcPPuplkB76QJgis8P9PUvXZiMZs=; Domain=.fedex.com; Path=/; Max-Age=7131; HttpOnly"
);
"server-timing" =     (
"cdn-cache; desc=MISS",
"edge; dur=651",
"origin; dur=52"
);
} })